# Can't declare lapacke.h after installing openBLAS

Tags: c++, lapack

I am a beginner to the openBLAS and LAPACK. The platform I used is Mac OS 10.8.5, Xcode 5.1.1.
after I `cd` to the folder stored openBLAS, I did as the following steps:

1. `make`;
2. `sudo make PREFIX=/usr/local/ install`;

all all these done, I want to declare `lapacke.h` in my code, but a error message: fatal error: 'lapacke.h' file not found.

I think that lapack will be installed when I install openblas without changing the makefile, could anyone help me with the problem?

Thanks @Francis,

the problem could be that the lapack header file can not be copied to `usr/local/include` folder, after `make` and `sudo make PREFIX=/urs/local install` , the information shows as following:

```
Generating openblas_config.h in /usr/local/include
Generating f77blas.h in /usr/local/include
Generating cblas.h in /usr/local/include
Copying LAPACKE header files to /usr/local/lib
install: illegal option -- D
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
make[1]: [install] Error 64 (ignored)
```

could anyone know how to deal with this problem? thanks.

Comment: Did you try to add the path to `lapacke.h` to the include search path of your compile command ? Something like `gcc main.c -o main  -I /somewhere_lapacke.h/ -llapack -lblas`

Comment: Thanks, Francis. I think it will works if adding a path to the code. But I do not know which location of the lapacke.h file. How can i get that path?

Comment: You may look in `.../xianyi-OpenBLAS-aceee4e/lapack-netlib/lapacke/include` or in `/usr/local/include`. If you get an error about the library, you might need to add the path to the library : `-L /usr/local/lib/somewhere_liblapack.a`

Comment: Thanks again, Francis. I checked the `/xianyi-OpenBLAS-aceee4e/lapack-netlib/lapacke/include` and I find the lapacke.h file but not in the `usr/local/include` folder, so how could install the package in `usr/local/include` folder? i.e., I would like to just write `#include <lapacke.h>` in the head file.

Comment: The command `make install` calls `Makefile.install` with something like `@echo Copying LAPACKE header files to $(DESTDIR)$(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY_DIR)` in the `install` target. As you installed using `make install`, did it print something like ` Copying LAPACKE header files to /usr/local/include` ? Other option : what does it print if you try `echo $NO_LAPACKE` ?

Comment: OK, I will try to install whole the things again. By the way, which step should I input the command 'echo $NO_LAPACKE' .

Comment: Just type it before  `make` or `make install`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66680/discussion-between-jack2007-and-francis).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on MacOS.

I found there is such line in the beginning of `make` output:

> OpenBLAS: Detecting fortran compiler failed. Cannot compile LAPACK. Only compile BLAS.

Solution:

- Install gfortran with `brew install gcc`;
- `make clean; make`;